# When is a IQueryable result materialized in Web API?

Tags: entity-framework, linq, asp.net-web-api

If I have a Web API controller where the database context is created using dependency injection. I have code like

```
    public IQueryable<Person> GetAll()
    {
            return dbContext.People;
    }
```

This works but I am trying to understand when does the IQueryable result get materialized? From my understanding it will be materialized when the result is iterated but I don't see any explicit code for that.

Comment: Your WebAPI has to serialise the result to JSON/XML so it will be done implicitly by that I would guess.

Comment: If you're using OData (http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/odata-support-in-aspnet-web-api/supporting-odata-query-options) the result from your action will not be materialized until the OData query has been executed. But yes, they'll be materialized before they're converted to XML or JSON or whatever.